# iOS - Will Apple reject In-app purchase promo code

Tags: ios

I want to create my own promo code for my in-app purchases.

For example, there will be a button is settings saying "promo" once the user press this button they will be directed to another view with a textfield.

If they enter their promo code, they can get in-app purchases for free.

Is this possible? Will Apple reject my app if I do this?

**EDIT**

I'm not talking about Apple promo codes, I am aware that Apple promo codes doesn't work with in-app purchases.

The promo code entered by users will be checked with my database. If the promo code is correct my app will unlock in-app purchases.

Comment: _"Promo codes don’t work for In-App Purchase products, including issues for apps in the Magazines & Newspapers category."_ (see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ProvidingPromoCodes.html))

Comment: @holex I'm not talking about promo codes made by Apple. I want to create my own promo codes, connect to my own database. Sorry if my question was unclear. I've edited my question.

Comment: yes, that may be rejected based on _"Apps may not include buttons, external links, or other calls to action that direct customers to purchasing mechanisms other than IAP."_ (see [here](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/))